# Can't find Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels Namespace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm new to Umbraco development.

My job is to upgrade from v7.3.6 to v7.14.0.

The Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels seems to be declared in umbraco/views/web.config.

[image]

However, Roslyn, the compiler seems to be throwing this error:

CS0234: The type or namespace name 'PublishedModels' does not exist in the namespace 'Umbraco.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

[image]

We have never used the modelsbuilder in our Umbraco system. My goal is just to get this working for now, so that we can be ready to migrate to v8 in the future.

Would this have something to do with the Temporary ASP.NET Files?

- I have reinstalled umbracoCMS + modelsbuilder a few times.
- I have updated to the latest asp.net.mvc
- I have updated to the latest microsoft.net.Compilers

I've been stuck on this for a while, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Umbraco: CS0234 The type or namespace name 'TextPage' does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074636/umbraco-cs0234-the-type-or-namespace-name-textpage-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the ModelsBuilder install guide ([here](https://github.com/zpqrtbnk/Zbu.ModelsBuilder/wiki/Install-And-Configure))

I needed to change the namespace in views/web.config from `Umbraco.Web.PublishedModels` to `Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels` as this is how it is defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to upgrade from v7.3.6 to v7.14.0. you will probably find more problems than just not being able to find that namespace.

The namespace Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels is a reference to the models that are generated by Umbraco when the Models Builder is enabled. However in version 7.3.6 this feature did not exist.

I recommend that you first use the  [Compare Releases](https://our.umbraco.com/download/releases/compare)` tool on the umbraco website. This will tell you exactly what changes (including breaking changes) that have happened between each version and give you specific instructions of what to look for when upgrading.

Another way I have done it in the past is upgrading version by version, that way you can isolate which version may be causing the problem.